# How does sum of reciprocals correlate with asymptotics

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics

A trivial example might be the harmonic series, where $\sum_{n\leq x} \frac 1 n \sim \ln x$ and asymptotically $n\sim n$.

Another example, the $n$-th prime is $p_n \sim n\ln n$ and $\sum_{p\leq x} \frac 1 p \sim \ln \ln x$.

The questions is, what can we say about the growth rate of $\sum
_{a\leq x} \frac 1 a$ if we know the asymptotics for $a_n$?

Comment: In many cases (including the two you cite) you can get somewhere by comparing the sum to an integral.

Comment: That pretty much answers the question… So, in the opposite direction, if the sum is asymptotic to $f(x)$, the $n$-th term should be about $\frac 1 {f'(n)}$?

Comment: If the sum to $n$ terms is about $f(n)$, the sum to $n-1$ terms is about $f(n-1)$, then the $n$th term is $f(n)-f(n-1)$, which approximates to $f'(n)$ under appropriate smoothness conditions.